# Exchange order between Global pooling layer and fully connected layer

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to create a new CNN model.
First I pass the images through a ResNet50 network. I now have 2 different ways to proceed.

Way 1: Insert a FCL with 512 neurons followed by a global average pooling layer.

Way 2: Do a global average pooling layer first, and only after do the FCL with 512.

Are way 1 and 2 equivalent? If not, which one is more correct?

Comment: What are the dimensions of ResNet50 output?

Comment: @gunes The output dimension is (None,7,7,7,25000).